# Differentiate between route change and page refresh in vue navigation guard?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I am working on a project where I need to push the user to sign in page if he is not authenticated, and my router guard is working fine.
however I don't want this code to run if the user refreshed the page or came directly to the link.
I want this because I want it to wait for user auto sign in which takes a few hundred milliseconds for firebase auth. But I do not want to wait every time the route changes only when the page is refreshed because firebase re-signs in the user only on page refresh not every router push.
this is what I want to acheive in theory

```
Routes.forEach((to, from, next)=> {
if(!isSignedIn && to.name != 'signInPage' && pageNotRefreshed) {
next('/sign-in')
}
else if (pageRefreshed && !isSignedIn && to.name != 'signInPage' ) {
// Wait 500ms and then run the upper condition one more time because firebase returns
// currentUser as empty as soon as page refreshes and takes some time to sign in and
// return isSignedIn  as true

}
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to solve your problem will be creating in App.vue watch block which will wait till value will change and then redirect user. I don't know where you store isSignedIn variable but I suppose in Vuex.

```
//get value from store
computed: {
  isLoggedIn() {
    return this.$store.getters.isSignedIn
  }
},
watch: {
  //listen for changes of value
  isLoggedIn(newValue) {
    //if user is not authorized yet redirect to login panel
    if (!newValue && this.$route.name !== 'sign-in') {
      this.$router.push('/sign-in')
    }
  }
}
```

With this solution you avoid hard coded waiting time (some people can have much bigger latency so 500ms will be too low value).